# onError does not load the default image - React

Tags: reactjs, image, default

What I am trying to achieve is that a particular image should be loaded for a div, when present. A default image should be loaded for all other divs for whom specific (depending on the name) image is not present.

```
const defaultImg = require('../images/default.jpg');
```

But this is the value that console returns for **defaultImg** -  "image /static/media/default.47ce6e77.jpg"

```
  <img src={require(`../images/${imageUrl}.jpg`)}    //if I remove ther require form here then the default image is loaded for eveerything, even when the particular image is present. 
      onError={(event) => event.target.setAttribute("src", {defaultImg})} alt="" />
```

Instead of the defulat image getting loaded, it throws

```
Error: Cannot find module './<image-name>.jpg'
```

I also tried using React Image Fallback

```
                {/* <ReactImageFallback
                src={require(`../images/${imageUrl}.jpg`)}
                fallbackImage={defaultImg}
                initialImage="loader.gif"
                alt="A cool image should be here"
                className="project-pic"
            /> */}
```

Doesn't work any different.

If `const defaultImg = require('../images/default.jpg');`

Why does it become `/static/media/default.47ce6e77.jpg` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your source in devtool. Your `img` might be showing as `<img src="[object Object]" alt="">`.

Replace your `onError` with `onError={(event) => event.target.setAttribute("src", defaultImg)}`. You are passing `defaultImg` as `object`.

Comment: Removing the curly brackets does not help. Still the same error
This is what the source shows " <img src={require(`../images/${imageUrl}.jpg`)}"

Answer (score 0):

Considerusing the fallback image:

```
<img src={imagesrc}
   onError={(e) => {
            e.target.onerror = null 
            e.target.src = fallbackImg}
} />
```